# How update a database table record in Zend?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-db

I am using select like this and it is fetching record successfully:

```
$table = new Bugs();
$select = $table->select();
$select->where('bug_status = ?', 'NEW');
$rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
```

But Now I want to update same record. For example in simple MySQL.

```
UPDATE TableName Set id='2' WHERE id='1';
```

How to execute above query in Zend ?

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
$data = array(
   'field1' => 'value1',
   'field2' => 'value2'
);
$where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $id)

$table = new Table();

$table->update($data, $where);
```

Comment: You sir get bonus marks for the `$where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $id)` shortcut.

Answer (score 12):

Since you're already fetching the row you want to change, it seems simplest to just do:

```
$row->id = 2;
$row->save();
```

Answer (score 10):

just in case you wanna increment a column use Zend_Db_Expr
eg:

```
$table->update(array('views' => new Zend_Db_Expr('views + 1')),$where);
```

Answer (score 4):

For more than one where statement use the following.

```
$data = array(
    "field1" => "value1",
    "field2" => "value2"
);
$where['id = ?'] = $id;
$where['status = ?'] = $status;

$table = new Table();

$table->update($data, $where);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function updateCampaign($id, $name, $value){
    $data = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'value' => $value,
    );
    $this->update($data, 'id = ?', $id );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   $data = array(
    "field1" => "value1",
    "field2" => "value2"
);

$where = "id = " . $id;

$table = new Table();

$table->update($data, $where);
```