# Update query updates all rows in database instead of particular row

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I am new to Zend framework and I am trying to update data in database and grid, but instead of updating particular row all rows are getting updated. please help me with this.

Here is my controller code.

```
public function editAction()
{

$form = new Application_Form_user();
$this->view->form = $form;

if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
{

$formData= $this->getRequest()->getPost();

if($form->isvalid($formData))
{
    $client= new Application_Model_DbTable_Client();
    $firstname = $formData['firstname'];
    $lastname = $formData['lastname'];
    $email = $formData['email'];

    $client->updateClient('Id',$firstname,$lastname,$email);

    $this->_helper->redirector('index');
}
else 
{
    $form->populate($formData);

}
}
else
{

    $id=$this->getRequest()->getparam('id');
    if($id>0)
    {

        $client= new Application_Model_DbTable_Client();
        $clients = $client->getClient('Id');

        $form->populate($clients[0]);
    }
}
}
```

And here is my model code.

```
public function updateClient($id,$firstname,$lastname,$email)
{
    $data=array('firstname'=>$firstname,
              'lastname'=>$lastname,
               'email'=>$email);
 $this->update($data,"Id=$id");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097234/how-update-a-database-table-record-in-zend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your code, so it looks like this:

```
if($form->isvalid($formData))
{
    $client= new Application_Model_DbTable_Client();
    $firstname = $formData['firstname'];
    $lastname = $formData['lastname'];
    $email = $formData['email'];

    $id=$this->getRequest()->getparam('id'); // define your id

    $client->updateClient($id,$firstname,$lastname,$email); // here, change Id into proper $id

    $this->_helper->redirector('index');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply andylibrian. I changed my Id into $id but it gives an error "undefined variable".

Comment: Have you added following line? `$id=$this->getRequest()->getparam('id'); // define your id` That code defines your id.

Comment: Sorry I didn't had defined id, now it's working properly. Thanks a lot for helping me with this.

Comment: You're welcome. If your problem has been resolved, you may want to accept my answer so others can see that this question has been answered. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
  $client->updateClient('Id',$firstname,$lastname,$email)
```

You're passing the literal string `'Id'` as the `$id` parameter to `updateClient`. Inside `updateClient`, you build a where condition with `"Id=$id"`. Your where condition becomes `where Id=Id`, which is true for every record, so every record is updated.

You need to pass a variable containing the actual ID of the record you want to update.